# 32 bit python on 64 bit windows machine

Tags: python, c++, windows, boost-python

I've downloaded pythonxy (2.7.6.1) on my new 64 bit Windows machine (Windows 7 Enterprise, SP1). When I try to run python, I get an error saying the side-by-side configuration was incorrect. WinPython 32 bit (2.7.6.3) shows the same behavior, WinPython 64 bit is fine.

However, I badly need to compile Python modules with boost and found myself taking the first few steps into what I believe will be searching-the-internet/configuration/compilation hell for 64 bit, so I'd rather try to make the 32-bit python work, for which I have my whole MinGW procedure set up and working. Does anybody know what I need to do in order to fix the side-by-side error? Install some redristributable package or something like that?

Comment: Check the Windows Event Log. IIRC, there should be an event that describes what dependency isn't installed correctly.

Comment: Activation context generation failed for "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\python.exe".Error in manifest or policy file "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.MANIFEST" on line 11. Component identity found in manifest does not match the identity of the component requested. Reference is Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.30729.5570". Definition is Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".

Answer (score 2):

From the event log message, it looks like it wants a newer version of the VC90 C-runtime.  Two options:

1. The installer may have installed a newer redistributable, but a reboot may still be required to finish the process.
2. Try installing the latest C-runtime distributable yourself:
   [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582).

Comment: Installed 2008 and 2013 Redistributable package (x86), the log/the error doesn't change. I have never had a problem like this. I recently installed MS Visual Studio Express, which I had never done before either. Can that have something to do with it?

Comment: Reading your error message more closely, it looks like it is finding an *older* version than actually found. The DLL in question should be MSVCR90.DLL. Perhaps you have an older version in the path somewhere that is being picked up?  The correct version should be in a subdirectory of C:\Windows\WinSxS.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18650202/235698) for a technique to monitor what DLL is being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I just got an answer from one of my colleagues who told me had the exact same problem. The solution was indeed downloading and installing a version of vcredist_x86.exe, but the trick is to find the exact right one. Apparently you can get to a page somewhere from where you can choose the right version. Sorry for not being able to give more exact information, I just have the file now and it works, but it doesn't even say the version number in the file name. This is all very obscure for my taste, but then I'm not a Windows guy.