# Cannot import a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, swig

I'm relatively new to Python and am trying to import some modules that were written by a 3rd party. They are called ok.py and _ok.pyd. I am trying to 'import ok', which references _ok.pyd, but it is not working. They are both in my site-packages directory, and I've added that path name to my Spyder PYTHONPATH variable. I've also tried putting them both in the current working directory, but to no avail.

All I do is type 'import ok' and I get the following error messages.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ok.py", line 15, in
> swig_import_helper
> return importlib.import_module(mname)
>
> File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib_*init*_.py", line 127, in
> import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>
> File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 967, in
> _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 670, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 583, in module_from_spec
>
> File "", line 1043, in
> create_module
>
> File "", line 219, in
> _call_with_frames_removed
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
> import ok
>
> File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ok.py", line 18, in 
> _ok = swig_import_helper()
>
> File "D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ok.py", line 17, in
> swig_import_helper
> return importlib.import_module('_ok')
>
> File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib_*init*_.py", line 127, in
> import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

The following is the ok.py code where it fails. I've done an image so line numbers are visible.

[image: ok.py]

Is there something easy I'm missing here, or is it unsolvable without the 3rd party vendor updating their code? It just looks like the importlib.import_module() cannot find _ok, but it is in the directory. When I type importlib.import_module() for other module names in that directory it works, so what are possible causes for this one not working?

Thank you.

Comment: you did activate your conda environment, right? `conda activate`

Comment: I did 'conda activate', no change. Other modules in the same directory are imported correctly with the importlib.import_module() method, but this one fails. It just looks like Python isn't able to find the file though, from the DLL load failed error.

Comment: You are probably missing a dependent DLL, such as a Visual Studio C runtime.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583061/c-dll-loads-in-c-program-not-in-python-ctypes/18650202#18650202) for a way to tell which one.

Comment: Mark, thank you so much. I downloaded this tool and it revealed there was a .DLL file that needed to be in a particular directory.