# Can't find DLL with PyInstaller on one PC but can on another

Tags: dll, pyinstaller, ctypes

**Preamble**

I've built a Flask app (with Python, obviously) that interacts via *ctypes* with a DLL that I've coded in C.  This works perfectly.

Then I used PyInstaller to package it up, adding `--add-binary ..\build\my.dll;build` to the PyInstaller invocation.  (I'm using the one-directory approach, not one-file.)

This works fine.  The final executable runs perfectly, just like the original Python version.

**Problem**

The tricky part is that it *doesn't* work on another PC.  It reports:

```
_main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll '\\path\\to\\build\\my.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
```

The reported path is correct.  And I even asked Python to list the contents of the directory immediately before trying to load the DLL, and it's there.

The (successful) primary PC and the (failing) test PC are both 64-bit Windows, and the DLL is 64-bit.

I'm at a bit of a loss.  I've tried using `--hidden-exports` too, but I think that's redundant with the explicit `--add-binary`.  I've tried making it fail on the primary PC by starting a new console and running from there (in case I'd set some paths up but forgotten, or there was something magic in my venv, but it stubbornly works ever time!).

Help me, SO, what have I missed?

Comment: Possibly the DLL is missing a dependency.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650202/235698 for a technique to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

@MarkTolonen pointed me in the right direction:

> Use [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).  Configure it to monitor the `python.exe` process for `CreateFile` operations:

What I learned from this is that my C DLL was referencing *another* DLL, and *that* was not found on the test PC.  (I thought I had statically linked all the code I needed into my DLL, but it turns out that I'd just linked with the stub library for the other DLL.)

I guess the important detail is that the error message said "failed to **load**", not "failed to **find**".  I was fixated on it meaning the latter.