# How can call C++ code in Python, that uses <iostream>

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, ctypes

I am trying to call some of my C++ machine learning code in Python. I have tried multiple other methods, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python) and [this explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-call-c-c-from-python/), both of which are very similar. I followed these to the letter, with the same filenames and code.

For example, I have the following C++ code...

### file.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void some_code()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!";
}

extern "C"
{
    void hello_there() { some_code(); }
}
```

I then compile it with...

> `g++ -c -fPIC file.cpp -o foo.o`

> `g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,lib.so -o lib.so foo.o`

#### code.py

```py
from ctypes import cdll

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib.so')

lib.hello_there()
```

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\some-path-here\1 - calling-cpp-with-python.py", line 5, in <module>
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib.so')
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\some-path-here\lib.so' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

What am I doing wrong? I have also tried with compiling it to a DLL file, and adding  `__declspec(dllexport)` before the *"void"* in the *extern* bit.

###### Additional Notes

If it is helpful...

- I am on Windows 10
- I am using the MinGW G++
- The name of the directory with the files in has spaces in it.
- This is running on Python 3.10, but the error also occurs in 3.9

Comment: You probably need to tell Python how to find the C++ standard library, because it is unlikely to be in a place where Python knows to look at. Can you compile a C++ *program* and the run it from a cmd window (not from a mingw shell)? If not, then it's the same problem you are seeing here.

Comment: You are using `.so` files in windows. I have doubt whether it will work or not, but probably WSL can help you. It looks like you have some path issue.

Comment: You can try removing the `./` part and write it like `lib.so`.

Comment: @akm, thanks, I do sometimes use WSL, so I shall try that.

Comment: However, I would still like to use Windows, to make my code cross-platform

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I have not used it in the mingw shell, but rather use the g++ that I installed alongside mingw

Comment: @akm I tried this on WSL, it works. Do you know of any windows solutions, perhaps with dlls?

Comment: So can you run a C++ program from within a cmd window?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583061/c-dll-loads-in-c-program-not-in-python-ctypes/18650202#18650202) for debugging which file can't be found.  The code works with the Microsoft compiler using `__declspec(dllexport` and `.dll` files.  Use a DLL and make sure the C++ runtime is also present in the same directory or DLL search path or it is statically linked

Comment: @Password-Classified Related, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330863/cant-import-dll-module-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) can help you...

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes I can.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I tried that, but it does not work.

Comment: OK try to examine (1) your library and (2) your executable in the dependency walker. Do you see a dependency in one that is not in the other? Also try building with `-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc` flags.

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate of [\[SO\]: Why does adding multiprocessing prevent python from finding my compiled c program? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75035737/4788546) (or [\[SO\]: Can't import dll module in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333711/4788546)). Read the instructions (including referenced *URL*s), add the corresponding paths and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a path issue based on the error. I was able to quickly try out your example, and it worked for me. This error probably has nothing to do with `iostream`, but you could confirm that by changing the function quickly to use `printf`.

I do not have experience working on c++ in windows 10, but could you check if you're able to find the library file in python, before accessing using something like the below code

```
import os    
print(os.path.exists('./lib.so'))
```

Comment: I have tried with printf, and the error does not  pop up

Comment: It works with printf, but I would  like to use iostream

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same problem on **Win 10, MinGW & Python 3.7-3.10**.

I finally used dependencywalker and found out that the importing relies on the compiler environment. With exaction of dependent dlls I solved this problem. Using static compile mode also helps.

Comment: Thanks for making the modifications; if you happen to remember, can you include the command line option (or other brief instruction) on how to enable static linking on the MinGW environment?

Comment: Can you explain how to use static compile mode?